# change images and/or css based on locale for i18n issues

Tags: image, jsp, spring-mvc, internationalization

I use spring MVC and I have arranged to change messages based on locale in JSP forms, using ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource and message tag of spring forms taglib. But what I want is to change images based on locale. Images are in CSS files and IMG tags in JSP.

What are the options for that? I know about themes in spring but I do not know how to attach them to LocaleChangeInterceptor.

Answer (score 4):

What you need is so called CSS Localization Mechanism.

There are few possible ways to do that. Built-in standard way would be to use CSS :lang pseudo-selector and write down lang attribute to be in-line with User Interface language:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      p:lang(en) {color:blue; background: white;}
      p:lang(pl) {color: white; background: red;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p lang="en">Some English text.</p>
    <p lang="pl">Jakiś Polki tekst.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

You get the idea. It just works, but unfortunately it will pollute your CSS files with tons of different per-language class definitions.

Otherwise, you will need to develop your own solution. As far as I know, no standard solution exists (at least it is not publically available). You may approach the problem in two ways: one would be to create your own servlet that will read the contents of per-language CSS file and serve it to Web Browser, other could be creating your own controller and write down path to per-language CSS file while rendering web page.

Comment: I like this idea when you only support 2 languages, but imagine what this would look like if you supported 10+ languages.

Comment: @ogc-nick: Sure, in that case standard CSS L10n mechanism is useless and you need to build your own (i.e. load per-language CSS which would override the defaults from regular CSS file). Nobody said that you need to stick to one method of doing things...